# Телефонная гарнитура на компьютер

Tags: аудио, драйвер, динамик

Подключаю телефонную гарнитуру к компьютеру через разветвитель, на микрофон и сами наушники. Оба работают исправно.

Внимание вопрос)

Как заставить работать кнопки на гарнитуре так, чтобы они управляли проигрывателем? В гугле ничего похожего не нашел. Как я понял (мультиметр мне помог), каждая кнопка замыкает цепь, исключая из нее микрофон и подключая разные резисторы, у которых сопротивление значительно меньше. В результате напряжение на выходе **увеличивается**, телефон получает информацию и выполняет операцию. Как заставить компьютер правильно обрабатывать эти команды?

[image]

Вот приблизительная схема замыкающихся контактов.

Программа должна определить замкнута цепь или нет. И желательно чтобы определяла какое в этой цепи сопротивление, то есть в общем определяла напряжение на выходе.

Comment: И что же это за пара?

Comment: Я только что опубликовал схему.

Comment: А причём тут программирование? Если я правильно понял, эта хрень (1) замыкает левый-правый каналы микрофона, чтобы на оба канала шёл  сигнал с микрофона-моно гарнитуры. А кнопки -- шунтируют сигнал с резисторами или просто замыкают на землю ("mute"). Не думаю, что их  нажатия можно поймать программно.

Comment: Да, ты правильно описал, при нажатии кнопок слабеет сигнал с микрофона или вообще пропадает. А поймать программно, телефон же ловит.

Comment: Не специалист в звуковых картах, но чтобы они фиксировали для драйвера изменение входного сопротивления микрофона, верится слабо. А уровень звука -- ну скажи потише, так это тоже должно отлавливаться?

Comment: Одно могу сказать, Артем, смотри даташиты и схему телефона - ибо что-то здесь не то.

Comment: Нет, уровень звука уменьшается в следствии частичного или полного исключения микрофона из цепи (я исправил рисунок). А отлавливаться должно напряжение на выходе.
3.4В если микрофон подключе;
1.1В если нажата одна кнопка;
0.5В вторая кнопка;
0В третья кнопка.

Comment: Ну что. Выделяйте постоянную составляющую (усередняйте уровень сигнала за некоторый промежуток времени) и, если средняя попадает в один из пяти уровней (для 3300ом, 471 = 3300*550/(3300+550), 151, 144, 0) -- генерируйте событие.

Comment: Вот мне и надо чтобы это сделал компьютер. Определил и выполнил событие.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не соответствует тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтоб измерить сопротивление в цепи микрофона надо приложить напряжение, но в компьютерах каналы входа и выхода звука физически разнесены. поэтому надо будет городить какую-то эл схему, причем из-за гальвонической рзвязки необходимо производить измерения не на постоянном токе со всеми вытекающими... эту схему необходимо от чего-то запитывать. Так что идея хрошая, но не реализуемая простыми средствами –